# How should I understand this line in D3.js' Hierarchy Layout Source?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/layout/hierarchy.js#L29

What's going on on line 29 here? Specifically:

```
if (value) node.value = +value.call(hierarchy, node, node.depth) || 0;
```

What's up with the `.call` invocation of `value` taking three arguments?

`value` is defined as a function taking one argument: `function(d) { return d.size; }`.

For `.call`, the first argument is the value for `this`, the remainder of the arguments are the arguments to the function to be called... since `value` only takes one argument, why are **three** arguments being passed in to `.call`?

Comment: `.call()` is calling the function given in the first argument with the thing before the dot as context and everything else as remaining arguments. That is, you're calling the function `hierarchy` with `value` as context and additional arguments `node` and `node.depth`.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff are you sure? the documentation for function.prototype.call() says the first argument is context: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: Lars is correct. The documented `function.prototype.call()` you linked to is not the same thing as d3 selections' `.call()` method. [This](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#call) is the documentation of the latter.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `value = d3_layout_hierarchyValue` on line 8 of layout/hierarchy.js which is just defined as a regular JS function, not a D3 selection type: `function d3_layout_hierarchyValue(d) { return d.value; }`.

Either way, what is the function call here trying to accomplish?